# Different length of sound files with different sampling frequencies

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, sampling

Im currently struggling to understand what is happening. So, I created a sound using the `audiowrite` function in Matlab (the sound is created using two different sounds but I dont think it matters) first with a sampling frequency of 44100 Hz, and another one, the sound file is the same but the sampling frequency is 48000 Hz. Now I'm observing that the sound produced at 44100Hz is approx. 30sec longer than the other one (48000Hz sampling). It looks like phase shifting of some sort, but I'm not sure. Any help/explanation is appreciated. I also made a amplitude/time plot for better understanding:

[image: here]

(I set the x axis to 350sec to see where the signal ends).

EDIT: here is the code for how I create the sound file:

```
[y1,F1] = audioread(cave_file);        %cave and forest files are mp3 files loaded earlier both have samp.freq of 48000Hz
[y2,F2] = audioread(forest_file);
samp_freq=44100;
%samp_freq=48000;                    
a = max(size(y1),size(y2));
z = [[y1;zeros(abs([a(1),0]-size(y1)))],[y2;zeros(abs([a(1),0]- size(y2)))]]
audiowrite('test_sound.wav', z,samp_freq);
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to load the audio and create this figure. Did you adjust the timestep accordingly in the time vector for each signal?

Comment: The figure is just for visualisation, the difference is seen even in the properties of the produced sound file (test_sound.wav and test_sound2.wav which is using the 48kHz samp. freq.)

Comment: You are loading two sounds with 48kHz sampling rate, and then writing them with a sample rate of 44.1kHz without resampling/interpolation, meaning that it indeed will become longer. Why not write it with the original sample rate (48kHz). What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What is the storage format? More specifically, is the info about sampling rate and number of channels stored in file meta data? which is then used during playback.

If so, then there are 3 possibilities for this behavior:
1) The sampling rate meta data of the 44.1KHz file is incorrect, while the audio was sampled at the correct rate i.e. 44.1KHz. Because the 44.1KHz file is playing longer than 48KHz, which I'm assuming to be producing the correct sound, and playing for the correct duration, it can be concluded that the sampling rate meta data of 44.1KHz is much lesser than 44.1KHz. 
Could you please check the meta data? or attach the files here so that I can try to take a look?
2) The sampling didn't happen at the correct rate, while the meta data has 44.1KHz as the sampling rate.
3) The number of channels is incorrectly stored.

In case the files are raw PCMs, then this probably the correct sampling rate and/or number of channels is not selected when playing the 44.1KHz file.

Hope this helps

Comment: I just found out about some calculations of duration (in secs) of the final sound file. It looks like this 

**duration = length(z)/samp_freq**

I think this explains the difference between those two sound files with two different samp. frequencies

Comment: I'm unable to understand. Let's take an example: Suppose we have a 10 second, single channel audio clip. We sample it first at 48KHz, 16bit and store it in file1. Then we again sample the original audio but with 24KHz 16bit and store it in file2. The file 1 will definitely be twice in size (number of bytes) than file 2. But still both files should play back for 10 seconds duration. Isn't it so?

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking but there is more to it. The *length(z)* in my case is the number of samples which is from the matrix *z* and the equation mentioned earlier actually produces the correct duration for the sound file and there is a 26sec difference between the produced files (in the one with more duration there are 26secs added from the sample y1).

Comment: did the above comment from @rinkert help ?

Comment: not really, but I already got my question answered. Thanks anyways